# How to interpret the differnce in results of check_property & msat_check_ltlspec_bmc counterexamples

Tags: model-checking, nuxmv

I created a generic SMV program and checked a pair of LTL properties using both `check_property` and `msat_check_ltlspec_bmc`. One property is found to be `true` with both commands. The other property, instead, gives a counter-example of *14* states with the first command and a single-state
counter-example with the latter command.

**Q:** why the second counter-example contains only one state, and how should it be interpreted?

```
MODULE Seq_19(T_41, T_41_PRESENT)
    VAR
            _next_t : { Init_46_idle, LO_51_idle, BO_73_idle, State_120_idle, LOSense_118, BOSense_115, TransitionSegment_125 };
        FlagLO : boolean;
        FlagBO : boolean;
        tt : -256..255;

    DEFINE
        LOOut_68 := 
            case
                (_next_t = LOSense_118) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        BOOut_84 := 
            case
                (_next_t = BOSense_115) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        LOOut_68_PRESENT := 
            case
                (_next_t = LOSense_118) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        BOOut_84_PRESENT := 
            case
                (_next_t = BOSense_115) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        guard_LOSense_118 := (tt > 5);
        guard_BOSense_115 := (tt > 10);
        guard_TransitionSegment_125 := TRUE;

    ASSIGN
        init(_next_t) := { Init_46_idle, LOSense_118 };
        init(FlagLO) := FALSE;
        init(FlagBO) := FALSE;
        init(tt) := 0;

    TRANS _next_t in { Init_46_idle }
         -> next(_next_t) in { Init_46_idle, LOSense_118 };
    TRANS _next_t in { LO_51_idle, LOSense_118 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { LO_51_idle, BOSense_115 };
    TRANS _next_t in { BO_73_idle, BOSense_115 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { BO_73_idle, TransitionSegment_125 };
    TRANS _next_t in { State_120_idle, TransitionSegment_125 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { State_120_idle };
    TRANS (_next_t = Init_46_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO;
    TRANS (_next_t = LO_51_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO;
    TRANS (_next_t = BO_73_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO;
    TRANS (_next_t = State_120_idle)
         -> next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(tt) = tt;
    TRANS (_next_t = LOSense_118)
         -> next(FlagLO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO;
    TRANS (_next_t = BOSense_115)
         -> next(FlagBO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO;
    TRANS (_next_t = TransitionSegment_125)
         -> next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(tt) = tt;

    INVAR ((_next_t = LOSense_118) -> guard_LOSense_118)
    INVAR ((_next_t = BOSense_115) -> guard_BOSense_115)
    INVAR ((_next_t = TransitionSegment_125) -> guard_TransitionSegment_125)
    INVAR ((_next_t = Init_46_idle) -> !(guard_LOSense_118))
    INVAR ((_next_t = LO_51_idle) -> !(guard_BOSense_115))
    INVAR ((_next_t = BO_73_idle) -> !(guard_TransitionSegment_125))
    INVAR ((_next_t = State_120_idle) -> TRUE)

   MODULE main
    VAR
        T_41 : -256..255;
        T_41_PRESENT : boolean;
        module : Seq_19(T_41,T_41_PRESENT);
```

With standard LTL model checking, I get the following output:

```
nuXmv > read_model -i Seq19-1210063772855777412.smv
nuXmv > go
nuXmv > check_property -l -p "G (!(((FlagLO = TRUE) & (tt < 5)))) IN module"
-- specification  G !(FlagLO = TRUE & tt < 5) IN module is true
nuXmv > check_property -l -p "G (!(((FlagLO = FALSE) & (tt < 5)))) IN module"
-- specification  G !(FlagLO = FALSE & tt < 5) IN module is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: LTL Counterexample
Trace Type: Counterexample
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    T_41 = -256
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module._next_t = Init_46_idle
    module.FlagLO = FALSE
    module.FlagBO = FALSE
    module.tt = 0
    module.guard_TransitionSegment_125 = TRUE
    module.guard_BOSense_115 = FALSE
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84 = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    module.tt = 1
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    module.tt = 2
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    module.tt = 3
  -> State: 1.5 <-
    module.tt = 4
  -> State: 1.6 <-
    module.tt = 5
  -> State: 1.7 <-
    module._next_t = LOSense_118
    module.tt = 6
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = TRUE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.LOOut_68 = TRUE
  -> State: 1.8 <-
    module._next_t = LO_51_idle
    module.FlagLO = TRUE
    module.tt = 7
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
  -> State: 1.9 <-
    module.tt = 8
  -> State: 1.10 <-
    module.tt = 9
  -> State: 1.11 <-
    module.tt = 10
  -> State: 1.12 <-
    module._next_t = BOSense_115
    module.tt = 11
    module.guard_BOSense_115 = TRUE
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.BOOut_84 = TRUE
  -> State: 1.13 <-
    module._next_t = TransitionSegment_125
    module.FlagBO = TRUE
    module.tt = 12
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84 = FALSE
  -- Loop starts here
  -> State: 1.14 <-
    module._next_t = State_120_idle
  -> State: 1.15 <-
```

Instead, with `msat_`-based LTL model checking, I get the following output:

```
nuXmv > reset
nuXmv > read_model -i Seq19-1210063772855777412.smv
nuXmv > go_msa
nuXmv > msat_check_ltlspec_bmc -p "G (!(((FlagLO = TRUE) & (tt < 5)))) IN module"
-- no counterexample found with bound 0
-- no counterexample found with bound 1
-- no counterexample found with bound 2
-- no counterexample found with bound 3
-- no counterexample found with bound 4
-- no counterexample found with bound 5
-- no counterexample found with bound 6
-- no counterexample found with bound 7
-- no counterexample found with bound 8
-- no counterexample found with bound 9
-- no counterexample found with bound 10
nuXmv > msat_check_ltlspec_bmc -p "G (!(((FlagLO = FALSE) & (tt < 5)))) IN module"
-- specification  G !(FlagLO = FALSE & tt < 5) IN module is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: MSAT BMC counterexample
Trace Type: Counterexample
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    T_41 = -256
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module._next_t = Init_46_idle
    module.FlagLO = FALSE
    module.FlagBO = FALSE
    module.tt = 0
    module.guard_TransitionSegment_125 = TRUE
    module.guard_BOSense_115 = FALSE
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84 = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the LTL property is checked with classic Tableau-based Model Checking. With this approach, the engine has a global view of the Finite State Machine represented in the model, and therefore it can provide a counter-example trace representing an (infinite) execution trace violating a given property.

In the second case, the LTL property is checked with Bounded Model Checking, which means that the engine advances the search by considering increasingly longer execution traces and lacks a global view of the Finite State Machine represented in the model. As a result, the counter-example returned by this engine always consists in some (finite) execution trace of minimum length.

In the given code example, the property `G (!(((FlagLO = FALSE) & (tt < 5)))) IN module` is already violated in the first state of the execution trace:

```
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    T_41 = -256
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module._next_t = Init_46_idle
    module.FlagLO = FALSE
    module.FlagBO = FALSE
    module.tt = 0
    module.guard_TransitionSegment_125 = TRUE
    module.guard_BOSense_115 = FALSE
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84 = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
```

Therefore, the returned solution is correct.

Comment: The following property is true with check_property but msat_check_ltlspec_bmc gives counterexample. The result of latter one seems to be correct."G (((tt >= 7) -> G ((FlagLO = FALSE)))) IN module". how do we explain this?

Comment: @RanjanaN can you edit your question or open a new one, showing me the counter-example?

Comment: Will open a new question from My computer in a while.

Comment: @RanjanaN please include the result of `check_fsm` too